# Double-clicking on a song in Finder launches Music.app but doesn't play it

Tags: macos, itunes, music.app

Back in the day of *iTunes*, when double-clicking on a song in *Finder* it oppened *iTunes* and started playing it.

Now, using *Music*, the same action only open *Music* and copies the song into it. Then I have to it play from the app (and search for that new song I just added).

How can I get back the open & play feature ? I checked in *Music*'s preferences and searched same issue on the web but nothing came up.

I'm using a 2017 Macbook Pro on Big Sur 11.6.1 and Music 1.1.6.37

Comment: i have a new 2020 iMac running Catalina and when I double click on a music file it starts playing instantly.  i can't find a setting for it, it just starts playing.

Comment: Then you just confirm my thought, my music.app is not behaving right ! Any idea why ?

Comment: i don't have a clue. i ouldn't find any setting that would turn that on.  i'll look again though.

Comment: Edd Growl, Testing in **macOS Big Sur** 11.5.2 and **Music** 1.1.6.37, _doubling-clicking_ on an .e.g. **MP3** _file_ in **Finder** _does_ automatically start playing in **Music**, whether it was closed or already opened. So, from that I have to assume it's the _default behavior_. Note that I have also tested in other versions of **macOS** and **Music** with additional _file types_ and in every case with a valid file supported by **Music**, the _default behavior_ occurred. In other words, it always played the _files_.

Comment: Note that these tests were done in clean installs of the versions of **macOS** tested with default setting for both the **OS** and **Music**.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe there is a setting in Preferences that causes the song to play. Here is an image of my Preferences Panel for the General settings.

[image]

And the panel for Playback.

[image]

Comment: None of those show any suitable option.

Comment: I know. i wanted to show the OP these panels and i didn't know how to show them  in comments